# Creating a list of modified lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Ok, so what I have are two constants that are lists of lists, but one is just like the other with an extra element. What I would like to do is be able to define these in a fairly clean way without having to duplicate the contents. So, for clairification I have something like this:

```
CONSTANT_ONE = [['val1', 'val2'], ['val3','val4']]
CONSTANT_TWO = [['val1', 'val2', 'extra_stuff'], ['val3','val4','more_extra_stuff']]
```

As you can see I'm duplicating the values in `CONSTANT_ONE`. I would like to avoid this if I can do so in a fairly clean way. I've tried:

```
CONSTANT_TWO = [l + extra for l in CONSTANT_ONE for extra in ['extra_stuff','more_extra_stuff']]
```

Which I feel is close, but doesn't quite do what I want as it will iterate through the second variable in the for loop for each item in the first. Is there a clean way to do this? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks much!

Comment: I smell an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It depends on your ultimate goal, but perhaps `itertools.chain` solves your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your list comprehension does, once you fix the type error (do `l + [extra]` instead of `l + extra`), is to create each combination, or the product of elements from both lists:

```
>>> [l + [extra] for l in CONSTANT_ONE for extra in ['extra_stuff','more_extra_stuff']]
[['val1', 'val2', 'extra_stuff'],
 ['val1', 'val2', 'more_extra_stuff'],
 ['val3', 'val4', 'extra_stuff'],
 ['val3', 'val4', 'more_extra_stuff']]
```

Instead, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the elements from the first list with the extra elements:

```
>>> [l + [extra] for l, extra in zip(CONSTANT_ONE, ['extra_stuff','more_extra_stuff'])]
[['val1', 'val2', 'extra_stuff'], 
 ['val3', 'val4', 'more_extra_stuff']]
```